# How to get status message of INSERT/UPDATE query using zxJDBC for postgresql database

Tags: jython, psycopg2, psql, postgresql-9.4

In psycopg2 we have cur.statusmessage to get execution status of query.
But, Is there any alternative to that in zxJDBC.

I am getting below error:

```
'com.ziclix.python.sql.PyExtendedCursor' object has no attribute 'statusmessage'
```